# Deleting a section of a block-oriented file in bash via matching a key/value pair

Tags: bash, sh

I look for the way since a moment to delete in my file, 3 lines, according to a given value (the name of the person in question).
I managed to delete the last lines of my file, but not to delete rows randomly after a value. Can you help me ?

test.txt - Before:

```
Name : Mike
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : Mould
Surname : Told
-----------------------------------
Name : May
Surname : Dery
-----------------------------------
```

test.txt - After with name "Mould" (not working):

```
Name : Mike
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : May
Surname : Dery
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you've currently tried (even though it isn't working)?

Comment: (BTW, "randomly" implies that what you want to delete is... well... a *random* block, one where the criteria is based on the operation of a random number generator. "Delete only the block that contains a given value" isn't random, but based on a pattern match; it's not necessarily an ideal choice of words, since folks coming in to offer expertise about random number generation in bash or such aren't likely to be helpful).

Comment: BTW, your input pasted here has whitespace on the ends of some of the lines. Is that legitimately valid in the input?

Answer (score 0):

#### General Practices

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describes reading content into bash line-by-line.
- [The Conditional Expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) on the bash-hackers' wiki describes the `[[ ]]` construct which can be used to do various tests regarding attributes of strings in bash (including comparing them against regular expressions or performing substring checks).

#### Putting This To Use

If you wrote a script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

key_to_delete=$1
value_to_delete=$2

sep_re='^-+[[:space:]]*$'
block=''
matched=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $sep_re ]]; then
    if (( matched == 0 )); then
      [[ $block ]] && printf '%s%s\n' "$block" "$line"
    fi
    block=''
    matched=0
  else
    if [[ $line =~ ^"${key_to_delete}"[[:space:]]+:[[:space:]]+"${value_to_delete}"[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
      matched=1
    fi
    block+="$line"$'\n'
  fi
done
```

...and, saving that script as `remove_kv`, ran:

```
remove_kv Name Mould <in.txt >out.txt
```

...then your `out.txt` would have the entry with the name of Mould removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gawk` like so:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n-[-]+\n"} 
      /\<Mould\>/{next} 
      {printf "%s\n-----------------------------------\n", $0}' file
```

Prints:

```
Name : Mike
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : May
Surname : Dery
-----------------------------------
```